# How can i use <symbol> instead of <g>?

Tags: svg, polymer

I'm trying to define my iconset-svg using a `symbol` tag instead of a `g` tag but it isn't working as the icon isn't rendered. If I define some icon using it works.

The code:

```
<iron-iconset-svg name="br-icons">
   <svg style="display: none">
    <defs>    
      <symbol id="icon-menu" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
        <title>menu</title>
        <path class="path1" d="M64 192h896v192h-896zM64 448h896v192h-896zM64 704h896v192h-896z"></path>
     </symbol>
   </defs>
  </svg>
</iron-iconset-svg>
```

I am using it like this:

```
<iron-icon icon="br-icons:icon-menu"></iron-icon>
```

Does anyone know how I can get this working?

Comment: I could not solution to use the symbol tag. I had to convert all my icons to use the tag g by illustrator manually.

Comment: For the time being you'll want to use <g> instead of <symbol>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response I got from the Polymer team was "you need to use a `<use>` element with a `<symbol>`, which doesn't let you style it". So I think for now you'll want to stick with `<g>`. Apologies if I'm mistaken here, I am not an SVG expert by any means :)